# How to get the value of key in List which has Hashtable

Tags: c#, hashtable

```
public static List<Hashtable> StoreSearchResult(NgWebDriver driver)
{
    List<Hashtable> searchList = new List<Hashtable>();
    Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
   // List<SEarchResult> searchResultList = new List<SEarchResult>();
    int numberofrows = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='contenttablegridsearchModal']/div")).Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberofrows; i++)
    {
        table.Add("ID",driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='row" + i + "gridsearchModal']/div[2]/div")).Text);
        table.Add("Date", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='row" + i + "gridsearchModal']/div[3]/div")).Text);
        table.Add("Type", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='row" + i + "gridsearchModal']/div[4]/div")).Text);
        table.Add("Sub-Type", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='row" + i + "gridsearchModal']/div[5]/div")).Text);
        table.Add("Description", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='row" + i + "gridsearchModal']/div[6]/div")).Text);
        table.Add("Score", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='row" + i + "gridsearchModal']/div[7]/div")).Text);
        table.Add("Asssigned-To", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='row" + i + "gridsearchModal']/div[8]/div")).Text);
        table.Add("Close-Reason", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='row" + i + "gridsearchModal']/div[9]/div")).Text);
    }
    searchList.Add(table);
    int sizeoftable = table.Count;
    int sizeoflist = searchList.Count;
    System.Console.WriteLine(sizeoftable);
    System.Console.WriteLine(searchList);
    return searchList;
}
```

I need to iterate the each item in list (which has Hashtable) with Key..

I'm iterating using Foreach but I am not getting option to pass the key value..

```
List<Hashtable> searchList = class1.StoreSearchResult(ngdriver);

foreach (var item in searchList)
{
  Hashtable tablevalue= item;
}
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean cycling all hashtable elements? If yes, like this:

```
        List<Hashtable> source = new List<Hashtable>();
        foreach (Hashtable hashtable in source)
        {
            foreach (object key in hashtable.Keys)
            {
                var value = hashtable[key];
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am getting another error while having multiple rows of data.. System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'ID'  Key being added: 'ID'... Instead of table.Add i have to use put option??

Comment: You're trying to add two identical keys and hashtable does not allow it. You can do something like if (hashtable.ContainsKey("ID")) hashtable["ID"] = value; else hashtable.Add("ID", value). If you need to manage multiple identical rows you can add more hashtable to searchList list.

Comment: I have to store Hashtable like this.. Java will allow me to use put method.{ID=11, Type="Retail"} {ID="12", Type="WholeSale"} {ID="13", Type="online"}. I do have multiple rows.. In Java if I pass index and key, it will return the value.. Is something there in C#?

Comment: If you always use ID as key, you can use that value as key: hashtable.Add(11, "Retail"); hashtable.Add(12, "WholeSale"): ecc. ecc.

Comment: This way i can not use Key as ID right? I have to pass key as 11, 12..??

Comment: Yes, the keys is your ID value. It's just an idea. Otherwise you can use everything as key for an hashtable, simple override the GetHashCode() method of your key object (every object has the GetHashCode() method).

Comment: Key is random value.. It would be good if i use as a Key then only my purpose solves.. Any other suggestion?

Comment: HashTable i used inside the for loop which solved my issue.. Thanks Luca. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's generally like `hashtable[key]`. That returns the value in the hash table, and you can also set the value like `hashtable[key] = value`

I regards to your example:

```
List<Hashtable> searchList = class1.StoreSearchResult(ngdriver);

foreach (var item in searchList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item[key]);
}
```

If you want to iterate through the hashtable:

```
List<Hashtable> searchList = class1.StoreSearchResult(ngdriver);

foreach (var item in searchList)
{
   foreach (var entry in item) {
       Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
   }
}
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/hashtable).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  foreach (Hashtable hb in searchList)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hb)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SOFAcrobatics
{
    public static class Launcher
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            Hashtable french_numbers = new Hashtable ();
            french_numbers ["zero"] = 0;
            french_numbers["cinq"] = 5;

            Hashtable english_numbers = new Hashtable();
            english_numbers ["zero"] = 0;
            english_numbers ["five"] = 5;

            Console.WriteLine(Launcher.SearchHashTablesByKey (new List<Hashtable> () {
                french_numbers,
                english_numbers
            }, "five"));

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        private static Object SearchHashTablesByKey (List<Hashtable> list, Object key)
        {
            foreach (Hashtable table in list)
            {
                if (table.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    return table[key];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```